# How can I convert this tuple to a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following tuple (list_permutation):

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

And I want to convert it in a list that looks like:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3]]...
```

This is my code that I've already tried:

```
result = [int(x) for x, in list_permutation]
print(result)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-fc7f88d67875> in <module>
----> 1 result = [int(x) for x, in list_permutation]
      2 print(result)

<ipython-input-63-fc7f88d67875> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 result = [int(x) for x, in list_permutation]
      2 print(result)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: `result = [list(x) for x in list_permutation]`

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Marek do you have a typo? Same as the answer below and works fine: https://repl.it/repls/VagueHighlevelBrains

Comment: @Marek - did you use `list` as a variable name somewhere? If so, you've reassigned the built-in `list` constructor - don't do that. You can get at the builtin in that situation with the `__builtins__` module, but it's a better practice not to use variable names that shadow the builtins.

Comment: in your link it works. But I use jupyter notebook and there the code doesn´t work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
new_l = [list(x) for x in l]
print(new_l)
```

This yields `[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]`.

Comment: I get an error: list object not callable

Comment: Looks like you've defined something as list. Try restarting @Marek

Comment: @Marek check my solution

Comment: @Marek The reason is that you have redefined `list` somewhere. If you have some variable, function, module or class named `list`, rename it to something else like `mylist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in built map function:

```
l = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
l = list(map(list, l))
print(l)
```

This should give you
`[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]`

Comment: `map` is outdated, except for some special cases. Though it has its uses, it is less readable than list comprehension and as such less favored.

Answer (score 0):

*Using map this can be achieved easily*

```
perm = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
perm_as_list = map(list, perm)
```

*Output below*

```
In [1]: perm = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
In [2]: perm_as_list = map(list, perm)
In [3]: perm_as_list
Out[3]: [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

list function can convert a tuple to list
you have a list of tuples so do the folowing:

```py
list_permutation=[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
result = [list(x) for x in list_permutation]
```